# Center a verbatim block with long lines, without using a minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verbatim, alignment, center

There are a lot of questions around centering verbatim blocks on the site, but trying them, they either hardcode the width of the verbatim block using a `minipage`, or they just don't work when the verbatim block has long lines. Here is an example of one such faulty centering strategy:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{centeredverbatim}{\expandafter\verbatim\centering}{\endverbatim}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{centeredverbatim}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
\end{centeredverbatim}
\end{document}
```

It produces:
[image]

What I want instead is that the block be centered, such that if it doesn't fit the page, it overflows on both sides, not just the right side.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [`fvextra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fvextra) package has some support for auto line-breaking in inline/block verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I use the `verbatimbox` package to create a verbatim hbox, which gets stored in `\theverbbox`.  I then output that box using `\centerline`.

Notes: The `\strut` is to get the proper vertical spacing before the verbatim stuff.  The `\leavevmode` option is so that blank verbatim lines are recognized and not ignored.  The `\scriptsize` is to make the very wide line small enough to fit on the paper.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim,verbatimbox,environ,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\strut

\begin{verbbox}[\scriptsize\leavevmode]
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
Next line in verbatim block

Last line in verbatim block
\end{verbbox}
\centerline{\theverbbox}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I make the verbatim block source its content from a text file `a.txt`?

Comment: @HappyFace `\verbfilebox[\scriptsize\leavevmode]{a.txt}
\centerline{\theverbbox}`

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but something to get you thinking. Use the `adjustwidth` environment to increase the textwidth for your verbatims.

```
% wideverbprob.tex  SE 615607

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage} % make adjustments to (local) page geometry
\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{centeredverbatim}{\expandafter\verbatim\centering}{\par\endverbatim}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Lipsum 1. \textbf{Default text width.} \lipsum[1]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in} % smaller margins, more text
Li[psum 2. \textbf{Wider text width.} \lipsum[2]
\begin{centeredverbatim}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
\end{centeredverbatim}

Lipsum 1. \lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\verb!1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 !
\end{center}

\begin{center}
Centered text.
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
Lipsum 4. \textbf{Default text width.} \lipsum[4]
\begin{centeredverbatim}
1 2 3 4 5 6
\end{centeredverbatim}
Lipsum5. \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Among other difficulties that I see:

1. your `centeredverbatim` does not work well within an `adjustwidth`
2. A (very) long centered verbatim will exceed the page width. Do you want line breaks as well?
3. How do you get line breaks in verbatim text?
4. If you don't want line breaks then you will have to choose a font size small enough to get your verbatim text to fit and/or choose a textwidth large enough to accomodate your long verbatim.

Comment: The `\verb!` example; Can it be written using a normal block?

Comment: "A (very) long centered verbatim will exceed the page width." I want either line breaks, or for the text to be centered such that its centermost characters are visible, but the leftmost and rightmost chars are placed outside the page.

Comment: @HappyFace Now you have completely changed your original question. Please ask a new one with your updated requirements. There might be some hesitation in trying to answer the new one in case you later change it. --- GOM